# MySQL if not null

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do the following without a `CASE` statement?

```
SELECT ifnotnull(field1, '!!!')
```

Now I'm currently doing the verbose:

```
CASE WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL THEN '!!!' ELSE field1 END
```

Comment: The suggested duplicate is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END` can always be simplified to `IF(x, y, z)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes:

```
SELECT if(field1 is not null, '!!!', field1)
```

which would be the same as

```
SELECT if(field1 is not null, '!!!', NULL)
```

Documentation on `IF` is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Comment: what if `field1` is `0`?

Comment: nope :) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: sorry to disappoint, but you're wrong. the expression `0 is not null` is true

Comment: @fantaghirocco you are confusing `expr1` with the value of a column.

Comment: the doc says something else *If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL), IF() returns expr2. Otherwise, it returns expr3. *

Comment: @fantaghirocco yeah, and the result of `expr1` is `1`, since `0 is not null` returns true

Comment: how can be `0` <> `0` ? it's not `expr1 <> FALSE`; it's `expr1 <> 0`

Comment: @fantaghirocco *sigh*. `expr1` means the *expression* that you are evaluating, in this case, `expr1` is  the result of `0 is not null`. What does `0 is not null` returns?, `1`, since it is true. Hence, `expr1` is `1`

Comment: @fantaghirocco please read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: @Lamak got it. I confused the expr result with the value of the column as you said. Thank you

Comment: I downvoted your answer due to a misundestrading of the - misleading in my opinion - mysql documentation. Can you please edit your question in order to allow me to retract the downvote? Thank you

Answer (score -3):

Try [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, '!!!')
```

Comment: this is kind of the opposite of what op wants